# How to insert data in Core data Based on Condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

Hi I am implementing application which is for 3 different languages like

> US, UK, AU

I am inserting data by using core data but here I want to insert data in those 3 languages at a time please any one help.

Here is the language type in `NSUserDefaults` and I am getting like below and inserting like the below but here if I put one string like

- `groupname:@"my list"` for one languge what the language  currently I am using  and
- `groupname:@"Name"` for remaing two languges i want to insert

how can I variate.

```
   NSInteger languageType  = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:TYPE_OF_ENGLISH] integerValue];
  [dbWrapper insertWordListGroupWithPictureGroupId:wordlistGroupId groupname:@"mylist":[[NSNumber numberWithInt:playerId] integerValue]:[[NSNumber numberWithInt:goaltype] integerValue] pictureGroupid:pictureCardGroupid mylistId:9998];
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question? Can you post, what's inside the insertWordListGroup... method?

Comment: -(void)inserMyList :(NSInteger)wordlistId groupname:(NSString *)groupName playerid:(NSInteger)playerId goaltype:(NSInteger)goalType mylistid:(NSInteger)mylistId
{
    TblMylist *mylistInfo =[NSEntityDescription
                            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TblMylist"
                            inManagedObjectContext:_managedContext];

Comment: mylistInfo.mylistid =[NSNumber numberWithInt:mylistId];
    mylistInfo.goaltype =[NSNumber numberWithInt:goalType];
    mylistInfo.playerid =[NSNumber numberWithInt:playerId];
    mylistInfo.wordlistgroupid =[NSNumber numberWithInt:wordlistId];
    
    mylistInfo.wordlistgroupname=groupName;
    
    NSError *error;
    
    if(![_managedContext save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save :%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
}

Comment: this is way i am saving data in coredata thanks for quick response

Comment: and i am able to get current language and i am able to insert data but i want to insert remaing two languages along with current language

Comment: Hi have you got my question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Don't get it either and all your weird comments that show code don't help ;) I posted an answer that answers the question as it is asked. Please tell us WHAT you wanna do and what is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `languageType` as additional param to the method `insertWordListGroupWithPictureGroupId` and there do the needed derivation by placing an `if statement` inside the method